# AngularJS ng-repeat for all IDs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular in an application.

I'm getting data from my db in an array with items like:

```
        $ordersall[$count] = array(  
        "orderID" => $looporders["orderID"],
        "customerID" => $looporders["customerID"],
        "customerName" => $customerName,
        "orderDate" => $looporders["orderDate"],
        "orderDeliveryDate" => $looporders["orderDeliveryDate"],
        "orderStatus" => $looporders["orderStatus"],
        "orderdetailID" => $row["orderdetailID"],
        "productTitle" => $productTitle,
        "productPrijs" => $productPrijs,
        "aantal" => $row["orderdetailAantal"],
        "extras" => "",
        "extrasprice" => ""            
    );
```

Now I want to print out this data for each ORDERID, per ORDERID I want to display: customerName, orderDate and the orderdetails like product, price, extras,... etc. But an order ID (ex: 5) can have multiple orderdetails and so multiple product names, prices, extras etc.

When I only have 1 orderID I solved it like this:

**Angular**

```
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("NavCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'orderoverview/58').then(function (results) {
        $scope.categories = results.data;
        $scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++){
        var categories = $scope.categories[i];
        total += (categories.productPrice * categories.orderdetailAantal);
        if(categories.extra1 != "")
        {
          total += categories.extrasPrice;
        }        

    }
    return total;
}
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
                <div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
                    <div class="sm-st clearfix">
                        <!--<span class="sm-st-icon st-red"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></span>-->
                        <div class="sm-st-info">
                            <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
                            <span>Sander Hofman</span>
                            <p>1 minutes</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat= "p in categories" ng-hide="categories.extra1.length">
                                {{p.orderdetailAantal}}  {{p.productTitle}} <br>
                                + {{p.extra1}} {{p.extra2}} {{p.extra3}} {{p.extra4}}
                                </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="totalprice">{{ getTotal() }} euro</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But now how can I accomplish that in html I have a list item for every orderID and all of its orderdetails?

example:

**orderID: 5**

orderdetail1: productTitle, price, quantity

orderdetail2: productTitle, price, quantity

orderdetail2: productTitle, price, quantity

**orderID6:**

orderdetail1: productTitle, price, quantity

**JSON SAMPLE**

```
[{"orderID":4,"customerID":1,"customerName":"Sander Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 09:49:06","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"done","orderdetailID":2,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":3,"productTitle":"The Coach","productPrijs":3,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":4,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":5,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":3,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":22,"customerID":11,"customerName":"Tom Welslau","orderDate":"2015-04-20 14:15:12","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":22,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":22,"customerID":11,"customerName":"Tom Welslau","orderDate":"2015-04-20 14:15:12","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":23,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""}
```

Comment: Could you add some sample json? you want to be using `angular.forEach`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the way the server returns **JSON**

If the JSON would be nested Array ( every order has an Array of products), you could easy accomplish it in two ng-repeats

```
 <li ng-repeat= "p in categories" ng-hide="categories.extra1.length">
       {{p.orderID}}
       <ul>
           <li ng-prepeat="product in p.products">
            {{product.title}}
          </li>
       </ul>
 </li>
```

So maybe solution would be to change the way on how the server returns JSON data? (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would be to present a list of orders first. When a user selects a particular order then you can navigate to a different view to show order details. This is important for scalability. However if you want to continue with your approac, you can achieve it by using a nested ng-repeat as shown below

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
<span>{{order.orderID}}</span>
<span>{{order.customerID}}</span>
<span>{{order.customerName}}</span>
<span>{{order.orderDate}}</span>
<span>{{order.orderDeliveryDate}}</span>
<span>{{order.orderStatus}}</span>

<div ng-repeat="orderDetail in order">
    <span>{{orderDetail.orderdetailID}}</span>
    <span>{{orderDetail.productTitle}}</span>
    <span>{{orderDetail.productPrijs}}</span>
    <span>{{orderDetail.aantal}}</span>
    <span>{{orderDetail.extras}}</span>
</div>
```

This will work provided your data is such that each order in the JSON data has also attached to it all the order details for that order

Below is a sample JSON data to illustrate the point

[{"orderID":4,"customerID":1,"customerName":"Sander Hofman","orderDate":"2015-04-20 09:49:06","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"done",
orderDetails:[
{"orderdetailID":10,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":11,"productTitle":"Sexy2 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":12,"productTitle":"Sexy3 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":13,"productTitle":"Sexy4 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":14,"productTitle":"Sexy5 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""}
]},
{"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Francis Ezengige","orderDate":"2015-04-20 09:49:06","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"done",
orderDetails:[
{"orderdetailID":20,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":21,"productTitle":"Sexy2 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":22,"productTitle":"Sexy3 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":23,"productTitle":"Sexy4 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderdetailID":24,"productTitle":"Sexy5 Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""}
]}]

If you study the above well, you will observe that after the fields in the primary order table, a field called orderDetails follows. The value of this field is an array whose elements are objects of type order detail. so I have in the sample an array of 2 orders each having 5 items in the orderDetails. so the ng-repeat repeats all the orders but in each order also repeats each item in orderDetails

As for a sample code it simply involves returning JSON data in the format above. the exact implementation depends on the server type you are using.

Comment: A little correction here pls. the second ng repeat should be  ng-repeat="orderDetail in order.orderDetails" where each order would have an array of order details called orderDetails

Comment: I'm trying to understand your approach but it would be much easier if you could provide a angular code sample as well

Comment: Hmm I'm getting a "Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1